# Accessing php variable

Tags: php, arrays

I can ask for help.
When I print out the php array content:

```
var_dump($ rowData);
```

I get an extract:

```
 Array ( [0] =>   ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( [0] => 162 [1] => 238 [2] => 331 [3] => 102 [4] => 103 [5] => 101 [6] => 99 [7] => 102 [8] => 103 [9] => 46 ) 
Array ( [0] => 53 [1] => 63 [2] => 48 [3] => 70 [4] => 30 [5] => 63 [6] => 63 [7] => 50 [8] => [9] => 33 ) 
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) " " } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(3) "162" [1]=> string(3) "238" [2]=> string(3) "331" [3]=> string(3) "102" [4]=> string(3) "103" [5]=> string(3) "101" [6]=> string(2) "99" [7]=> string(3) "102" [8]=> string(3) "103" [9]=> string(2) "46" } [3]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "53" [1]=> string(2) "63" [2]=> string(2) "48" [3]=> string(2) "70" [4]=> string(2) "30" [5]=> string(2) "63" [6]=> string(2) "63" [7]=> string(2) "50" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(2) "33" } }
```

How can I get into the variable: values 162 and 53

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and add the output. What are you expecting to happen for the rows that don't have those values? Are you asking how to access an array index, or use [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) for example?

Comment: var_dump extract looks:

Comment: just use a `foreach()` look and get the first index value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need the first two rows, I think you should do some validation to make sure empty values don't get entered into the array if you don't need them.

But if you really want to use that array, and you need to access those specific values, you need to access it by index, the below snippet makes an array similar to yours, and you can see how I accessed the values you asked about in your question.

```
<?php

//This is just to emulate the array you presented
$arr[][0] = null;
$arr[] = null;
$arr[][0] = 162;
$arr[][0] = 53;

var_dump($arr);

echo "first value you want: ".$arr[2][0];
echo "\nsecond value you want: ".$arr[3][0];

?>
```

here's a screenshot of the file running (also, if you want to see how to do something like this in a foreach loop and have a specific goal in mind with this, comment on my answer and I'll edit it).

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot for help.